# receives an incomprehensible value and it is not clear how it gets it

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I wrote functions for finding duplicates in an array, passed two test cases without problems, but in one test case I don’t understand how it gets access to a value from the array.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogoQg.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvVRv.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvUou.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnd1.png)

```
int compare(const void * x1, const void * x2){
  return ( *(int*)x1 - *(int*)x2 );
}
int* findDuplicates(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
    int *p = (int*) malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
    if(numsSize == 1){
        *returnSize = 0;
        return p;
    }
    qsort(nums, numsSize, sizeof(int), compare);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        if(i == numsSize - 1){
            break;
        }
        if(nums[i] != nums[i + 1]){
            continue;
        }
        p[k] = nums[i];
        ++k;
        *returnSize +=1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

I can solve it through XOR but I’m just wondering why it gets the data in the second test case, and I don’t understand how he gets it.

Comment: Do not post text data as image. Please [edit] your question and include any important information as *text*.

Comment: @user694733 I tried but it doesn't show the whole code as text, it shows part of my code. I don’t know why, it’s not a convenient editor

Comment: @user694733 oh everything worked. but I didn't do anything in the editor, it worked on its own

Comment: "I can solve it through XOR" What does that mean? Finding duplicates doesn't seem to be proper application for bitwise or logical XOR

Comment: `if(i == numsSize - 1)` If you don't want to handle last value in your loop, why don't you just stop the loop earlier? `for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)` => `for(int i = 0; i < numsSize-1; i++)`

Comment: `*returnSize +=1;` What is initial value of `*returnSize`? Where do you take care about it?

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh thank you. I just fell asleep at 3 am and woke up at 8 to quickly solve a problem in leetcode and move on, so my head is not very clear right now.

Comment: @Gerhardhoh that's a good point too.

Comment: @Gerhardh why is XOR using it a bad idea?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you! it worked! after I did *returnSize = 0; I would never have thought that it was possible to pass a raw pointer to functions. how can I make your decision correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw pointer"? The caller just did not initialize the variable before passing its address to you.

Comment: @Gerhardh when I said raw pointer, I meant what you just said. Is a raw pointer not the same thing as an uninitialized pointer? I mean the value by address.

Comment: Using `qsort` violates the requirement "runs in O(n) time", and your dynamic allocation violates "uses only constant extra space". You need a different solution.

Comment: @RuslanPseush A "raw" pointer is just a pointer (and is a term usually only used in C++). An uninitialized pointer is a pointer that isn't initialized and hasn't been assigned a value; e.g. `int *p;`.

Comment: The pointer is initialized. It points to a variable in the caller's functions. That variable just doesn't hold a defined value before you are called.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know that I can make this function faster, I just feel empty in my head due to the fact that I didn’t sleep properly. I just wanted to do it quickly and go on to sleep, but when I saw the error in the second test case, I wondered how this could be, and why in the first and third test case it passes and works fine, but in the second there is an error.

Comment: @Gerhardh and thanks for explaining the raw pointer notation.

Comment: @molbdnilo and thanks for explaining the raw pointer notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize the counter variable.

```c
*returnSize +=1;
```

If the caller does not initialize to 0 before calling you (and you should never ever rely on the caller!) you start with indetermined value which causes undefined behaviour.

Besides that, you should also resize the allocated memory. You allocate memory for too many entries.
As a maximum, you can have `numsSize/2` duplicates.
After you know the correct number of duplicates, you could use `realloc` to shrink your array.